# How to smoothly fade in/ fade out an element after giving it a display:none value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm aware of the many questions here on Stack Overflow similar to this one which all get resolved by using `visibility:hidden` instead of the `display:none` property. The problem I have is I think I must use `display:none` because I need to fill the space of the div being hidden with an alternate div, `visibility:hidden` would just preserve that space while making it invisible.

MY GOAL: after the **+** button is clicked the `nav` element correctly fades out. After this animation I have a JavaScript line that counts 500 milliseconds and then gives the faded div a class containing `display:none`.

The problem is when the now **-** button is clicked, I give the element back its `display:block` property and remove the class that was giving it its blur/fade effect. **But instead of a nice fade/in transition, the element just instantly pops back on the screen. No animation**.

I'm at a loss for how to fix this while continuuing to use the `display:none` property. **Thanks for the help and I'm not using any libraries like jQuery, just plain vanilla Javascript.**

```js
var expand = document.getElementById("expansion");

function removeElm() {
  "use strict";
  document.querySelector("nav").classList.add("removed");
  document.querySelector("#description").classList.remove("removed");
}

function expandF() {
  "use strict";
  var navLi = document.querySelectorAll("li"), i;
  
  if (!document.querySelector("nav").classList.contains("out")) {
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.add("out");
    document.querySelector("body").style.background = "#dff";
    document.getElementById("expansion").innerHTML = "-";
    document.getElementById("expansion").style.background = "#f00";
    
    for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
      navLi[i].classList.add("rsHover");
    }   
    setTimeout(removeElm, 500);
  } else {
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.remove("removed");
    document.querySelector("#description").classList.add("removed");
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.remove("out");
    document.querySelector("body").style.background = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("expansion").innerHTML = "+";
    document.getElementById("expansion").style.background = "#222";
    
    for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
      navLi[i].classList.remove("rsHover");
    }
  }
}

expand.addEventListener("click", expandF);
```

```css
/*///////////////////////////////// __NAV__ /////////////////////////////////*/
nav {
  display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; right: 19px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); margin: auto
}
nav ul:after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both } /* << clearfix */

nav ul { font-size: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
nav li { width: 150px; height: 150px; list-style: none; float: left; margin: 5px}
nav li:hover { background: #055; color: #eee; cursor:pointer }
nav span {
  display: block; position: relative; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
/*///////////////////////////////// SECTION /////////////////////////////////*/
#description {
  display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; right: 19px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); margin: auto
}
/*///////////////////////////////// _MISC__ /////////////////////////////////*/
.removed { display: none !important }
.rsHover:hover { background: #dff }
.out {
  -webkit-filter: blur(60px); filter: blur(60px); color: #fff; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.9); transform: scale(0.1, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); font-size: 110%;
}
/*///////////////////////////////// _ANIM__ /////////////////////////////////*/
body{ -webkit-transition:2s ease; transition:2s ease }

nav{
  -webkit-transition:color 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition:color 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition:filter 1s ease, color 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
  transition:filter 1s ease, color 1s ease, transform 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, 
  -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    html,body { height: 100%; text-align: center; color: #222; margin: 0 }
    #expansion {
      float:left; position: relative; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%); width: 28px; height: 28px; padding: 5px;
      margin: auto; color: #666; font-size: 150%
    }
    #expansion:hover { background: #222; color: #eee; cursor:pointer; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="expansion">+</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><span>one</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>two</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="description" class="removed">
    <h1>about web</h1>
    <p>
      WEB is a reference of...
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force the browser to render the element after setting `display: block` to make sure the element is in the document flow, as otherwise it won't do any transitions or animations. Use reflow:

Your element in current hidden (`display: none`) state:

```
<div style="display: none; opacity: 0; transition: opacity 500ms"></div>
```

JS to make it in flow and then transition to opacity: 1:

```
div.style.display = 'block';
div.clientHeight; // Forces the browser to "reflow"
div.style.opacity = 1; // Now the element will transition from opacity: 0 to opacity: 1
```

Where `div` is the HTMLElement object. Note that `opacity` is just an example.

I strongly suggest you read this to understand more (as it's a really complex topic): http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

**edit**: changed `currentHeight` to `clientHeight`.

Comment: Please elaborate or edit my code snippet. Not sure exactly what you are saying.

Comment: @inspectrum When you want to restore the element, set `display: block`, access the `.currentHeight` property of the element, and then apply whatever styles/classes you want the element to transition to.

Comment: I took your suggestion, but unfortunately it still hasn't fixed my problem. Check out this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tynhyur/. Did I implement it right? ( commented where i added your code )

Comment: Finished version implementing this technique: https://jsfiddle.net/6tynhyur/1/. Thanks to @Kaiido for pointing out the typo.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks for that, was in a rush.

Answer (score 0):

You can also play around with adding or removing event listeners in the same button to foce it do different things.

I'm not an expert in JS, but i've seen that sometimes, if your javascript changes classes and styles inside the same function, the browser will execute the changes simultaniusly messing up with some of your animations.

In this examle below, I use a dirty trick to force the code to do one thing after another. If you don't do this, the fadein won't work.

```js
// To remove
document.querySelector('.remove').addEventListener('click', remove);

function remove() {
  // Reconfig the button
  var button = document.querySelector('.remove');
  button.removeEventListener('click', remove);
  button.classList.remove('remove');
  button.classList.add('add');
  button.addEventListener('click', add); // New functionality added
  // Now make your changes
  var element = document.querySelector('.test');
  element.classList.add('fadeout');
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.style.display = 'none';
  }, 500);
}

function add() {
  var button = document.querySelector('.add');
  button.removeEventListener('click', add);
  button.classList.remove('add');
  button.classList.add('remove');
  button.addEventListener('click', remove);
  var element = document.querySelector('.test');
  element.style.display = 'inline-block';
  // Dirty trick incomming!
  setTimeout(function() { // force the change of the class after the change of display
    element.classList.remove('fadeout');
  }, 1); // do this after 1ms of the previews command
}
```

```css
.remove,
.add {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.test {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  opacity: 1;
}
.fadeout {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="remove">Click to toggle element below</div>
<div class="test">testing block</div>
```

Comment: Let me add that to play around with the adding and removing of events, you need to use named functions or it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var expand = document.getElementById("expansion");

function removeElm() {
  "use strict";
  document.querySelector("nav").classList.add("removed");
  document.querySelector("#description").classList.remove("removed");
}

function expandF() {
  "use strict";
  var navLi = document.querySelectorAll("li"), i;
  
  if (!document.querySelector("nav").classList.contains("out")) {
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.add("out");
    document.querySelector("body").style.background = "#dff";
    document.getElementById("expansion").innerHTML = "-";
    document.getElementById("expansion").style.background = "#f00";
    
    for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
      navLi[i].classList.add("rsHover");
    }   
    setTimeout(removeElm, 500);
  } else {
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.remove("removed");
    document.querySelector("#description").classList.add("removed");
    document.querySelector("nav").classList.remove("out");
    document.querySelector("body").style.background = "#fff";
    document.getElementById("expansion").innerHTML = "+";
    document.getElementById("expansion").style.background = "#222";
    
    for (i = 0; i < navLi.length; i++) {
      navLi[i].classList.remove("rsHover");
    }
  }
}

expand.addEventListener("click", expandF);
```

```css
/*///////////////////////////////// __NAV__ /////////////////////////////////*/
nav {
  display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; right: 19px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); margin: auto
}
nav ul:after { content: ""; display: block; clear: both } /* << clearfix */

nav ul { font-size: 100%; text-transform: uppercase; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
nav li { width: 150px; height: 150px; list-style: none; float: left; margin: 5px}
nav li:hover { background: #055; color: #eee; cursor:pointer }
nav span {
  display: block; position: relative; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}
/*///////////////////////////////// SECTION /////////////////////////////////*/
#description {
  display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; right: 19px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); margin: auto
}
/*///////////////////////////////// _MISC__ /////////////////////////////////*/
.removed { display: none !important }
.rsHover:hover { background: #dff }
.out {
  -webkit-filter: blur(60px); filter: blur(60px); color: #fff; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1, 0.9); transform: scale(0.1, 0.9);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%); transform: translateY(-50%); font-size: 110%;
}
/*///////////////////////////////// _ANIM__ /////////////////////////////////*/
body{ -webkit-transition:2s ease; transition:2s ease }

nav{
  -webkit-transition:color 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition:color 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, -webkit-transform 1s ease;
  transition:filter 1s ease, color 1s ease, transform 1s ease;
  transition:filter 1s ease, color 1s ease, transform 1s ease, -webkit-filter 1s ease, 
  -webkit-transform 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <style>
    html,body { height: 100%; text-align: center; color: #222; margin: 0 }
    #expansion {
      float:left; position: relative; top: 50%; -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      transform: translateY(-50%); width: 28px; height: 28px; padding: 5px;
      margin: auto; color: #666; font-size: 150%
    }
    #expansion:hover { background: #222; color: #eee; cursor:pointer; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="expansion">+</div>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><span>one</span>
      </li>
      <li><span>two</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="description" class="removed">
    <h1>about web</h1>
    <p>
      WEB is a reference of...
    </p>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: What did you change.